# NativeScript Is there a way to include a css file with a view model instead of by a views

Tags: css, nativescript

Is there a way to include a css file with a view model and not a view?

I've tried looking at the nativescript documentation and have not been able to find the answer

This view model is used/presented in a number of different views so adding the css classes to each view folders css file works but makes it harder to maintain as I now have duplicate css classes floating about in different folders.
Alternatively i could put it in the global css file however this can quickly become too large of a file if i need to do this for multiple view models/ styles.

Use case:
A list of items that get validated in an async manner which will change css class based on status (simple use case example background-color changes to: white/red/yellow/green).

please note that I am coding a non-angular app.